# Why does react-app (in typescript) cannot hot reload upon editing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, nvm, wsl-2

There are *three* cases. All occur on Window 10 WSL Ubuntu:

1. I created a new React app with `--template typescript` this week. After `yarn start`ing, all kinds of editing do not trigger any hot reloading at all.
2. I `yarn start`ed an old React app (created with `--template typescript`) which was created at July 2020. The configs on `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` did not revise since their creation, but no hot reloading can be triggered.

   package.json (built on July 2020)

   ```json
   {
     "name": "00_test",
     "version": "0.1.0",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
       "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
       "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
       "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
       "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
       "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
       "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
       "react": "^16.13.1",
       "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
       "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
       "typescript": "^3.7.2",
       "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
     },
     "scripts": {
       "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start",
       "build": "react-scripts build",
       "test": "react-scripts test",
       "eject": "react-scripts eject"
     },
     "eslintConfig": {
       "extends": [
         "react-app",
         "react-app/jest"
       ]
     },
     "browserslist": {
       "production": [
         ">0.2%",
         "not dead",
         "not op_mini all"
       ],
       "development": [
         "last 1 chrome version",
         "last 1 firefox version",
         "last 1 safari version"
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

   tsconfig.json (built on July 2020)

   ```json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "lib": [
         "dom",
         "dom.iterable",
         "esnext"
       ],
       "allowJs": true,
       "skipLibCheck": true,
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
       "strict": true,
       "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
       "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
       "module": "esnext",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "resolveJsonModule": true,
       "isolatedModules": true,
       "noEmit": true,
       "jsx": "react-jsx"
     },
     "include": [
       "src"
     ]
   }
   ```
3. I created a new react-app (with js only) this week,
   after `yarn start`ing, all kinds of editing do not trigger any hot reloading at all.

Weird thing is, in all 3 cases, NO usual auto-popping a new browser is triggered after **Compiled successfully!**

I googled a lot but only one not-applicable case (which specified with webpack problem) is found. And react's github page shows no similar issues.

My env change from July 2020 to now:

1. A new ASUS wifi router (AC68U) with complex network config option is used;
2. VS-code is upgraded to v1.53.1 (Jan 2021 ver);
3. Windows 10 is kept upgraded;
4. WSL2 is used instead of WSL1;
5. nvm is added to manage nodejs version

Comment: `PORT=4000` is non-standard for CRA - [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714583/how-to-specify-a-port-to-run-a-create-react-app-based-project) seems to suggest you need to use `set PORT=4000 &&` on a windows machine.

Comment: Thanks, actually the PORT=4000 script is for avoiding clash of port 3000 with other more bulkier apps. Tried running thru 3000 actually but hot reloading still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with WSL2. Try set version to version 1.

Here a link to a answer with all steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773488/4261884